# How to prove function surjective

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I must prove that given function is surjective for all natural numbers. How to do that? Please include detailed explanation.

$g:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ $g(x) = x^2+1$

I am trying to solve but I cannot continue:
$$y = f(x)$$ $$y = x^2+1$$
$$y -1 = x^2$$
How must I contunue from here?

Comment: What is the domain and codomain of $g$?

Comment: domain is $ \mathbb{N}$ and codomain is $ \mathbb{N}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$g:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ is not surjective.

For example, there is no $x\in\mathbb{N}$ (codomain) such that $g(x)=9$, because $g$ is increasing and $g(2)=5$ and $g(3)=10$, so $9$ is skipped.

Comment: does my calculations in proper direction?

Comment: @TeodorKolev  If it were surjective, then you were on the right path yes. In that case you would only need to take the square root. But in this case, you only need to find a counterexample, so just trying out some values or drawing the function.

Answer (score 0):

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}$
$$
g\left(x\right)=n \Leftrightarrow x^2=n-1
$$
Then
$$
x= \pm \sqrt{n-1}
$$

However$\  g(x) \ne 0$ for all $x$ ( except if $x=i$ ) but depends on your domain of $g$.

Comment: "but depends on your _domain_* of $g$."